# docker mysql permission denied

Tags: mysql, docker, centos7, permission-denied

I'm using the Centos7 system, I have a /docker folder that is shared on the network (temporarily to transfer data) I'm trying to run mysql pointing /docker/mysql as a folder to persist data but I'm having an error that I didn't understand how to solve it

```
[root@localhost docker]# sudo docker run --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mysql -e MYSQL_USER=user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=userpass -v /docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql mysql
2022-08-31 19:15:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
find: '/var/lib/mysql/': Permission denied
find: '/var/lib/mysql': Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql': Permission denied
```

could someone help me please?

Comment: the same command works for me with a different folder of course. Try to change `/docker/mysql` and it should work for you are well. Then check the rights on the network drive. You can also use a local folder and then shutdown the container and manually move the data on the shared drive

Comment: @Mihai 
I tried, same error (taking the 2 lines of "find") I tried with "--user root" also same error

Comment: @Mihai 
so far I've only been able to start mysql without using volume for persistence

Comment: the container already runs as root so you don't need `--user=root`. Try using a docker volume instead of a local folder (`-v mysql_vol:/var/lib/mysql`). this way docker creates the volume with the correct permissions and it should work. Question: the folder on the host that you try to map, do you create it before or do you let docker create it?

Comment: @Mihai 
the folder was created before and is being shared on the network using samba-server, using docker volumes works, can i point samba-server to the docker volumes folder?

Comment: no. that is managed by docker and sharing it might mess things up. Better double check the right on `/docker` and `/docker/mysql`. It would also be better to let docker create the `mysql` folder when you run the container, so not create it before

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the file `/var/lib/mysql` exists or not. Sometimes the Mysql file is in `/var/lib64/mysql`, so you can use `/var/lib64/mysql` instead of `/var/lib/mysql`.